# How do I remove elements from a single page application?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension, single-page-application

I am trying to remove elements from linkedin's website inside a div element with class `.core-rail` with my Google Chrome extension.

However, when I remove an element and navigate away, the pages I navigate to are also affected. I am currently using `MutationObserver` and calling remove() on elements that need to be removed. Any ideas of how I can remove elements without messing up other pages on the website?

Here is my `MutationObserver` code:

```
const DEL_SELECTOR = ".core-rail";
const mo = new MutationObserver(onMutation);
// in case the content script was injected after the page is partially loaded
onMutation([{addedNodes: [document.documentElement]}], true);
observe();

function onMutation(mutations, hideElements) {
  console.log("script test runs");
  const toRemove = [];
  for (const {
      addedNodes
    } of mutations) {
    for (const n of addedNodes) {
      if (n.tagName) {
        if (n.matches(DEL_SELECTOR)) {
          toRemove.push(n.children);
        } else if (n.firstElementChild && n.querySelector(DEL_SELECTOR)) {
          var matches = n.querySelectorAll(DEL_SELECTOR);

          for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
            toRemove.push(...matches[i].children);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if (toRemove.length) {
    mo.disconnect();
    for (const el of toRemove) {
      try {
        //el.setAttribute('display', 'none');
        el.remove();
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
    observe();
  }
}

function observe() {
  mo.observe(document, {
    subtree: true,
    childList: true,
  });
}
```

My (reduced with just necessary info) `Manifest.json`:

```
{
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["https://www.linkedin.com/feed*", "https://www.linkedin.com/feed/"],
            "run_at": "document_start",
            "js": ["block.js"]
        }
    ],
    "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",
        "background"
  ]
}
```

Comment: `MutationObserver` is listening as long as it lives (as long as the extension code is in the air). So it does not care which page is now in the browser. I don't know what you want to achieve but you may need more specific in your query selector.

Comment: @George If you're trying to have your Chrome Extension *only function on LinkedIn's page*, you can place that restriction in your `manifest.json` file. Check here for manifest.json docs: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/manifest/. IF you are using a content script to manipulate the DOM, you'll want to explicitly match the CS Script url with the linkedin URL. See here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/content_scripts/#declaratively

Comment: Sounds like you might need to use history api to connect/disconnect your MutationObeserver

Comment: @George alternatively, if you need to toggle an element based on the URL, instead of removing it, set its css display property to None to toggle it off and then replace it by swapping the css property

Comment: @Benny you're absolutely correct, I hadn't noticed it was running on all other pages as well. I specifically set my content script with the `MutationObserver` to only run on the `/feed` URL yet it is running on all other URL

Comment: @ZAR I have tried that, but it seems to set display to none on all pages because my content script with the `MutationObserver` is running on all pages.

Comment: @George I may be able to help if you share your `MutationObserver` code. By `/feed` you mean LinkedIn pages that match this pattern?

Comment: @George and you aren't able to restrict which pages via content script matching patterns? https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/match_patterns/ Would be helpful to know which urls/pages you are referring to.

Comment: @Benny that would be super helpful! I have shared the code in the original post. By feed, I mean `linkedin.com/feed` or `linkedin.com/feed*`. I want to remove anything inside `<div class="core-rail"> </div>` only on those URLs

Comment: @ZAR I've updated the post with my manifest.json. My URL matches seem to only launch on the `linkedin.com/feed`  URLs, though it is running when I click on other pages such as `linkedin.com/notifications` Do you spot anything wrong with my link matches?

Comment: @George out of curiosity, what if you change in `manifest.json` to `"run_at": "document_idle"`?

Comment: @charlietfl you got it. After further digging, my MO was only running, even though my js file wasn't supposed to be active. Didn't know it could do that. I disconnected it each time after using and reconnected when the user moved onto the /feed URL and that did the trick.

Comment: @George , Benny's comment is good. Additionally, depending on how you've st up your extension, you may have to declare the url match in host_permissions on the manifest as well, https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/declare_permissions/#host-permissions

Comment: @Benny looks like the manifest wasn't the issue. For some reason the MutationObserver was still running despite the rest of the script being inactive. Thank you so much for your help! It was through debugging the mutationobserver code that I realized this

Comment: @George glad to hear you nailed it. It's a good tip for me too that MO is active and should be deactivated on page unload